# datetime format in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need to display a datetime column in my gridview, but I don't want to show millin second for sure. How do I set the format string in gridview to display a datetime data in following format:
08-19-2007 11:09 AM

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the appropriate [`DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) for the bound field.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="YourDateField" HeaderText="SomeHeader" 
                    DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt}"  />
```

Alternatively, you could use `DateFormatString="{0:g}"` which is the general date/time pattern (short time). It would produce something like `08/19/2007 11:09 AM`

Comment: I believe HH will display military time and AM/PM.

Answer (score 12):

You can also check if you are using Template Field.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submission Date">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("dbDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:tt}")%>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 6):

Date Time Format with AM/PM:

```
HtmlEncode="false" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}"
```

Answer (score 3):

A suitable format string would be:

```
{0:MM-dd-yyyy H:mm tt}
```

A good resource on making custom format strings in .Net can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

To format a DATETIME value in a GridView, you can do it like this:

```
DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt}"
```