# Reading date from sql date format adds extra 12:00:00 AM?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview

While reading data of sql server from gridview ,the date column adds an extra 12:00:00 AM to the end of the date.

eg:9/29/2013 12:00:00 AM

In the gridview it shows this way, but i only have a **date** type date saved in the sql table.

I need that to be only 9/29/2013.

same thing happened while reading and displaying that in a textbox , but it could be solved this way

```
DateTime date =Convert.ToDateTime(VoucherDetails["voucher_date"]);
                          TextBox3.Text = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

any solutions for the gridview ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235324/datetime-format-in-asp-net-gridview

Comment: It was useful and worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a bound field.

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TheDateField" HeaderText="HeaderText" 
                DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}"  />
```

All you should have to do is add DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" to your bound field.

Answer (score 0):

For the Grid View see [datetime format in asp.net gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235324/datetime-format-in-asp-net-gridview).  However, you can also change your SQL Query to cast the time columns as a DATE.  That will cut off the time portion as well.

Answer (score 0):

To format a DATETIME value in a GridView, you can do it like this:

DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}".